# Strange behaviour in CENTOS 7 where binary is not available as root, but is available to user data process

Tags: centos, root

In AWS EC2, I am using Centos 7, I observe strange behaviour where a binary for Hashicorp Vault CLI (/usr/local/bin/vault) is available during boot to commands I run in user data.  It is also available for users normally.  However, if I run `sudo -i` it is not available.  If I run `sudo su - root`, then it is available!

Why would a command be available in user data as root, but not if I try to login as root using `sudo -i`?

Comment: What do you mean by "available"? What happens when root runs `/usr/local/bin/vault`?

Comment: Because you're ending up with a different $PATH between `sudo -i` and `sudo su - root`.  `sudo -i` is instructing sudo to behave as if it's a login, `sudo su - root` is instructing su to behave that way.  Read the man page for each command to understand the behavior.